# page doesn't load on refresh - react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have basic react app with the following pages: Home, Profile, contact, and experience.  I have set up the routes for each page but when I go to a different page other than home, it renders but when I refresh page, the page doesn't load.

I noticed if I add the `#` before the page name, for example `http://localhost:1234/#/profile` the page renders.  So i'm confused why I need to the `#` which I don't want and I'm using `react-router-dom`, so there is no need for `#`.

I added the `historyApiFallback` to my webpack.config but that doesn't work.  Can anyone help me with this?  I'm new to react and I want to learn as much as possible.  Your help will be appreciated!

App.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar";
import Intro from "./components/introPage";
import Experience from "./components/experiencePage";
import Profile from "./components/profilePage";
import Contact from "./components/contactPage";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className="pageSections">
                    <Navbar />
                    <div className="navContent">
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Intro}/>
                        <Route path="/experience" component={Experience}/>
                        <Route path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
                        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

navbar.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Navbar extends Component {
    render(){
        return (

            <div className="navFrame">
                <Link to="/">
                    <div className="topNav"><div className="navBar"><h3>Marteen</h3></div></div>
                </Link>

                <Link to="/profile">
                    <div className="rightNav"><div className="navBar"><h3>Profile</h3></div></div>
                </Link>

                <Link to="/experience">
                    <div className="bottomNav"><div className="navBar"><h3>Experience</h3></div></div>
                </Link>

                <Link to="/contact">
                    <div className="leftNav"><div className="navBar"><h3>Contact</h3></div></div>
                </Link>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Navbar;
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = {
    entry:  __dirname + '/js/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss?/,
          loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader' 
        }
      ]
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './',
        hot: true
    }
};
module.exports = config;
```

package.json

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p --progress --config webpack.config.js",
    "dev-build": "webpack --progress -d --config webpack.config.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack --progress -d --config webpack.config.js --watch",
    "start": "npm run open",
    "open": "concurrently \"http-server -a localhost -p 1234\" \"open http://localhost:1234\""
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.6.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "webpack": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "npm": "^5.10.0"
  }
}
```

**Update**

[image]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "fullstack_profile",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "fullstack profile with flask and react",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p --progress --config webpack.config.js",
    "dev-build": "webpack --progress -d --config webpack.config.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack-dev-server --hot --progress --mode development",
    "start": "npm run open",
    "open": "concurrently \"http-server -a localhost -p 1234\" \"open http://localhost:1234\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/medev21/fullstack_profile.git"
  },
  "author": "martin",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ]
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/medev21/fullstack_profile/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/medev21/fullstack_profile#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.6.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "webpack": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "npm": "^5.10.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = {
    entry:  __dirname + '/js/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss?/,
          loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader' 
        }
      ]
    },
    devServer: {
      contentBase: __dirname + '/dist',
      compress: false,
      port: 1234,
      historyApiFallback: {
        index: 'index.html'
      }
    }
};
module.exports = config;
```

[image]

Comment: I know gatsby uses localhost:1234 - is that what you're using for this? I didn't think react-router was something you implemented yourself into gatsby - they have a link component you can download / install to achieve this. Apologies if I'm miles off.

Comment: Have you tried `devServer: { contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'), ... }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why http://localhost:1234/#/profile works is because # doesn't reload the page. It behaves the same as an anchor tag in HTML where you stay on the same page but scroll to a specific section of it. For example, the below scrolls you to the portfolio section of the page.

```
<a href="www.page.com/#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
```

If you omit the #, this is different. This tells your server to reload the page and visit that location. In your case http://localhost:1234/profile is unknown by the server as you have not specified it on the server side. In these cases, you need to either create the route or proxy the request when the route is not found.

As you are using react-router which is a client-side router, the same file needs to be served by the server and therefore you should go with the proxy option.

When using `http-server` [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) say you can add the -P or --proxy flag to specify it.

> -P or --proxy Proxies all requests which can't be resolved locally to the given url. e.g.: -P http://someurl.com

In your case update the below in your package.json.

```
"open": "concurrently \"http-server -a localhost -p 1234 -P http://localhost:1234\" \"open http://localhost:1234\""
```

An alternative is to use `webpack-dev-server` for development. It'll improve your developers experience a lot as it supports hot reloading when a component changes.

install it using `npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server`

Add the below to your webpack config.

```
devServer: {
  contentBase: __dirname + '/dist',
  compress: false,
  port: 1234,
  historyApiFallback: {
    index: 'index.html' // assuming this is your entry point file that loads your bundle.
  }
},
```

Then in your package.json add a script for it and run it using `npm run watch`

```
"watch": "webpack-dev-server --hot --progress --mode development",
```

**NOTE:** Make sure that in your dist folder `index.html` is present. If it isn't you will run into issues.

I've created a [basic project on GitHub](https://github.com/rscheffers82/webpack-boiler-plate-with-dev-server) so you have a working example.

Comment: I chose the latter option but still getting the same issue; installed `webpack-dev-server` and added the `watch`.  Not sure if I'm missing something, how do i specify the urls in the server side?

Comment: There's no need to specify these URLs on the server as you're using client-side rendering. The only thing the server/dev-server needs to know is that it needs to serve a fallback file when it cannot find a file/directory on the server. That's all you need.

Comment: As for your main file that loads the page. Can you verify that the path is correct and the index file is named as specified? Make sure the `contentBase` en  `historyApiFallback: { index: }` options are correctly set. They are key here. When they are not, the server won't have a proper fallback and you'll get page cannot be found error.

Comment: I have set in `devserver` the following: `contentBase: __dirname + '/dist',` and `historyApiFallback: {
        index: 'index.html'
      }`. Still get the same issue, when i refresh the page the page gets an error, cannot find page.

Comment: Are you running `npm run watch`? You should before visiting http://localhost:1234. I've created a basic project so you can see it in action. You'll find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/rscheffers82/webpack-boiler-plate-with-dev-server)

Comment: Thanks for providing the basic project but unfortunately still getting the same error in the basic project, can't even get to `localhost:1234`.  I'm wondering if I'm missing something in my setup, I'm assuming yours is running fine.

Comment: Yes i have run `npm run watch` before visiting `localhost:1234`.  Not sure why I'm getting the page error on my project and the basic project.

Comment: I just realized, there was no index file in the basic project

Comment: Yes, I just saw that just now. Run these commands in order and you should have the dev-server up and running. `git pull origin master`, `npm install`, `npm run dev`, `npm run watch`

Comment: ok, the basic project works and the page refresh as well.  I noticed in the basic project, it has the `copy-webpack-plugin`, does this have to do with the refresh page?  Other than that, everything is pretty similar

Comment: The `copy-webpack-plugin` is only needed to copy the html file to the `dist` folder nothing else. You could copy it manually and it would work too. The main part to make the dev-server work is `devServer` section in the webpage config.

Comment: ok, so i noticed that when i run `npm run dev` in the basic project, the logs shows `bundle.js`, `./index.html` and `Entrypoint main = bundle.js`.  However on mine, it only shows `bundle.js`.  It looks like it's not finding the `index.html`, so it sounds like a path issue.  Attached it's an image of the tree file of my project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176970/discussion-between-roy-scheffers-and-medev21).

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution to Express and at least to Heroku deployment

I want to share my solution that finally allowed the user to access every link in my React App.

After reading these proposed solutions and [this helpful article](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/), I could manage to make this works with this following code in my main `server.js` file:

```
// Serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files for the React frontend app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')))
// This solves the "Not found" issue when loading an URL other than index.html.
app.get('/*', (req, res) => { //n3
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html'), err => {
    if (err) { res.status(500).send(err) }
  })
})
```

- Make sure to always point the path to build which is where all the files are loaded in the production environment.
- After that, all urls are working well finally!